# Add DataValidation to an unknown number of Rows

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Hi I want to add validation to every row in a column of an excel file. I'm using EP Plus for handling the creation and reading of excel files. Here is the code I have tried.

```
var codeValidation = codeListSheet.DataValidations.AddTextLengthValidation("A2:AN");
```

But this isn't working it says that it overlaps with the range of my next column

```
var paretnCodeValidation = codeListSheet.DataValidations.AddTextLengthValidation("B2:BN");
```

I know there should be an easy way of doing this but I can't find the answer. Hopefully there is someone who has come across this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK my bad the answer was in the [FAQ on the EP Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Documentation)

To Select an entire column you can use A:A or B:B etc

Comment: Hi, is it possible to add validation to column except first row and second row? thanks

Comment: i posted my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29764226/add-list-validation-to-column